# How to set up a document web server

Tags: webserver

I have no experience in setting up servers.
So... How do you set up a web server that hosts documents like the example below?

[image]

Comment: If you put files in the folder "RFC" on your server, the files will be listed on that web page

Comment: Googling for "*apache howto*" gives a dozen++ links on the first page! Prior to asking this question you might have liked to read to FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: i know the FAQ and i did a google, i just did not know what to google for. i always thought apache is only related to websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, the basic apache installation should work. If the directory does not contain an index.html (or any of the other valid indices), then it will display the directory contents as per your example.

NB: Ensure that your apache config permits directory listing, by including `Options Indexes andThenSomeOtherStuffMostLikely` in the directory-definition in your httpd.conf. For example, here's the default on my webserver, which permits it:

```
<Directory "/usr/www/default/http">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Now, if apache has both read and execute access to the directory (which it should have), then it'll display as an index.